# Getting error when update mac os from Mavericks (10.9.5) to El Capitan (Latest version)

Tags: upgrade, macos

I want to update my mac mini OS from Maverics to EI Capitan.

When i click on **Get** button at that time it will give a error message. For better understanding i attached screen shot of the error message.

[image]

Also i attached screen shot of the mac mini configuration.

[image]

I tried with removing cache folders from the **/private/var/folders** path but not working.

In above path i found folders, which name is **7s** and **zz.** Also remove the folder which name is **com.apple.appstore** for remove the temporary files.

Please provide appropriate solution for upgrade the mac os.

Comment: I guess you already canceled the download, closed the App Store completely, deleted the folder contents, opened the app Store again and restarted the download?

Comment: Yes, i do these steps but not working. The same error becomes when click another time for download.

Comment: Can you give us more specs on your Mac? Age, memory left, etc.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/kb/SP728?locale=en_US

Comment: @CalebKleveter As per **support** link i match whole configuration, it is fulfill with my Mac mini.

Age:- 17 months old

For memory left almost it is 3GB after starting required application. Though it is another way for finding memory left then please tell me.

If you want another information about system then fell free to ask me.

Comment: The spec page shows two things 1) 2GB of memory, 2) 8.8GB of available storage. That means you need at least 2GB of RAM, and 8.8GB of storage left on your internal hard drive. You probably knew that, but I thought I would point it out just in case.

Comment: @CalebKleveter Yes i know about the memory. Also i try with 2GB+2GB = 4GB memory but not working it. Also my system have more than 400GB available storage. Thank you for reply..

Comment: Looks like you are saying you signed in with a developers ID, can you sign in with a normal Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

After formatting mac OS solving the issue.
Do reinstall OS 10.9.5 (Maverics) from safe mode of mac OS.
After reinstalling upgrade OS EI Capitan from app store, this is the only solution which i done in my case.